# Nginx suddenly slow for downloading files

Tags: linux, nginx

Since one week ago Nginx became terrible slow for downloading small files and serving my content. For example downloading a 500kb file wend from ms to 6 sec on the same server. it feels like its being throttled somehow. The strange part here is that i did not change any config files of Nginx in the last months.

So i have checked if its something with my server. I uploaded and downloaded a file via sftp and i reach 900mb/s on a 1gb connection. I also checked cpu and disk usage, but all seems to be ok.

I did some tests with Postman and i see that the time for the actual HTTP response itself is some ms, but afterwards downloading the file takes long.

Its Also strange that this happens when i using HTTP and not HTTPS. HTTPS works completely fine local network but if i download the same file over HTTPS from outside our network its slow again. HTTP is always slow.

I'm not sure what to do now, or what else that i can check. I also created a new Ubuntu VM with the same configuration and i have the same problem there, so my guess its something with the configuration but i don't know what.

Here is my nginx.conf file

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;


events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;

     gzip_vary on;
     gzip_proxied any;
     gzip_comp_level 6;
     gzip_buffers 16 8k;
     gzip_http_version 1.1;
         gzip_min_length 256;
     #gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
         gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/x-font-ttf font/opentype image/svg+xml image/x-icon;
    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

        ### Include a blocklist file
        include /etc/nginx/nginx-acces.conf;
}


#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
# 
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#}
```

This one of my sites-enabled configs:

```
server {
    server_name resources.example.io www.resources.example.io;
    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://192.168.1.105:8083;
        allow all;
    }


    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/resources.example.io/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/resources.example.io/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

server {
    if ($host = resources.example.io) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    server_name resources.example.io www.resources.example.io;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

Comment: almost 3 years later, I have the same problem